# Rename first time a row reaches a set value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where I want to give a different name when the data reaches <0.5 for the first time. I only want to give a name to that specific event and not the events afterwards. So far, I have only been able to identify as a group, see below.

Is this possible?

Sample data set:

| Date and Time | Process value | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-06-07 00:00 | 8.2 | A |
| 2020-06-07 01:00 | 6.5 | A |
| 2020-06-07 02:00 | 4.3 | A |
| 2020-06-07 03:00 | 3.6 | A |
| 2020-06-07 04:00 | 0 | B |
| 2020-06-07 05:00 | 0 | B |
| 2020-06-07 06:00 | 0 | B |

Expected result:

| Date and Time | Process value | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-06-07 00:00 | 8.2 | A |
| 2020-06-07 01:00 | 6.5 | A |
| 2020-06-07 02:00 | 4.3 | A |
| 2020-06-07 03:00 | 3.6 | A |
| 2020-06-07 04:00 | 0 | Stopped |
| 2020-06-07 05:00 | 0 | B |
| 2020-06-07 06:00 | 0 | B |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first index of the condition by `.index[0]` and then use `.loc` to locate the row by that index and specify column to update it:

```
df.loc[df.loc[df['Process value'] < 0.5, 'Status'].index[0], 'Status'] = 'Stopped'
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

      Date and Time  Process value   Status
0  2020-06-07 00:00            8.2        A
1  2020-06-07 01:00            6.5        A
2  2020-06-07 02:00            4.3        A
3  2020-06-07 03:00            3.6        A
4  2020-06-07 04:00            0.0  Stopped
5  2020-06-07 05:00            0.0        B
6  2020-06-07 06:00            0.0        B
```

Comment: @Mel  Welcome!  Thanks for accepting my answer. Please consider also upvoting my answer (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)).

Comment: this will only work for the entire dataset as well, not as a group.

Comment: @jezrael  Fail if no match can be an expected outcome.  Sometimes better than no fail but doing nothing and did not got noticed.  Overall, no match, no update, still the expected result.

Comment: @Umar.H  Yes, for entire dataset.  Anyway, it is not explicit that the question requires first occurrence within a group.  Also not specifying what's a group.  My interpretation is that Status B could be the identified group by checking Process Value == 0 from the data.

Answer (score 1):

use a boolean and then `.groupby.idxmin()` to get the min index for each group.

then broadcast your value using `.loc`

```
s = df.loc[df['Process value'].le(0.5)].groupby('Status').idxmin()['Process value']

df.loc[s,'Status'] = 'stopped'


print(df)

   Date and Time  Process value   Status
0  2020-06-07 00:00            8.2        A
1  2020-06-07 01:00            6.5        A
2  2020-06-07 02:00            4.3        A
3  2020-06-07 03:00            3.6        A
4  2020-06-07 04:00            0.0  stopped
5  2020-06-07 05:00            0.0        B
6  2020-06-07 06:00            0.0        B
```